# Searchkick highlights unnecessary word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm highlighting unnecessary word for example I'm search for "Document CASE No. 2015-331"
here the list that searchkick will highlight

1. "Document CASE No. 2015-331"
2. "Not"
3. "no"
4. "on"
5. "case is"<----- this is very weird i dont know why this is
6. highlighted lol
7. "2015"
8. "2017"
9. "2018"
10. "2016"
11. "to"
12. "Not to"

here's what's my search looks like

```
    search = ::Document.search params[:q], fields: [:content], where: {id:
     params[:id]}, highlight: { tag: 'span class=match-matcher',
     fragment_size: @document.content.length}

    search.with_highlights.each do |document, highlights|

       document.content = highlights[:content]

    end
```

the goal here to highlight the "Document CASE No. 2015-331" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your field has been analyzed when indexed.
If you want to achieve the exact match and tokens should be searchable the mapping should be "not_analyzed" and the data needs to be re-indexed.

Here you are looking for exact match.

Modify the mapping for you field by adding something like below.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "city": {
        "type": "text",
         "fields": {
           "raw": { 
             "type":  "keyword"
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: where should I need to put the mapping?

Comment: please refer the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Comment: you give me the idea bro thanks I want to accept you the answer but I'm using Searchkick it this possible to accept your answer but I will give my own answer?

Comment: last question I have two parameters I have the q and id where shall I put that?

Comment: you cannot put it while quering(Assumed)...the above settings are done before the data is indexed to elasticsearch...